# Constant function $1$ on smooth manifold is sum of two function with the property that the support each of them is a disjoint union of compact sets

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have no idea why the constant function $1$ on smooth manifold $Μ$ may be written as the sum of two non-negative
smooth functions $1 =F_1 + F_2$ with the property that the support of each
$F_1$ and $F_2$ is a disjoint union of compact sets.

Please give me some detail from your idea.

Comment: Have you learned about partitions of unity on manifolds?

Comment: Alternately, are you familiar with exhaustion functions?

Comment: Yes, I learned about partition of unity. But I do not know that how it reduce to two functions with given property for its supports.

Comment: Can you find two such functions on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Kajelad I have no idea.

Comment: If the manifold is connected, the only way to do so is $1=1+0$.

Comment: @user10354138 why? Are you sure?

Comment: Recall support is closed: $\operatorname{supp}f=\overline{\{x\in X:f(x)\neq 0\}}$.

Comment: @user10354138: You are mistaken regarding $1=1+0$ the only solution (it is not even a solution!).

Comment: @user10354138 If $M=\mathbb{R}$ then $\operatorname{supp}1=\mathbb{R}$ that is not compact.

Comment: @bigli As a further hint, can you find a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:$$f(x)=1\text{  for  }x\in[4n,4n+1],\ \ n\in\mathbb{Z}\\f(x)=0\text{  for  }x\in[4n+2,4n+3],\ \ n\in\mathbb{Z}\\f(x)\in(0,1)\text{ otherwise}$$

Comment: @Kajelad  I could make your function on $\mathbb{R}$. But how does I use it for $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$?

Comment: @bigli Notice that $f$ and $1-f$ form the desired pair of functions on $\mathbb{R}$. For an arbitrary smooth manifold $M$, you can compose these two with an exhaustion function. (An exhaustion function is a smooth function $\varphi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ is compact in for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$. These can be shown to exist using partitions of unity.)

Comment: @Kajelad You are right that $f$ and $(1−f)$ form the desired pair of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that the support of each $f$ and $(1-f)$ is a disjoint union of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. For example: It is clear that $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\mathbb{R}-\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(4n+2,4n+3)$ and it is  a disjoint union of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. My question: Why is the support of $(f\circ\varphi)$ a disjoint union of compact subsets of $M$?

Comment: @bigli Note that $\operatorname{supp}(f\circ\varphi)\subseteq\varphi^{-1}(\operatorname{supp}(f))$, and $\varphi^{-1}([a,b])$ is compact.